# How to change jQuery global namespace

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a legacy project which uses 2 jQuery library versions: the "jQuery" global variable is in 3.5.1 and we have our custom "jdnd" which is the 1.10.2 version. I'm planning to replace the old one and use the latest version (3.7.1), but according to the previous team, they had to do a search/replace the word "jquery" into "jdnd" to have the custom "jdnd" global namespace.

I feel that that's not a good way. Is there a much easier way on how to not use the default $ or jQuery variable? Note that we are working on a platform and we have no control on which jQuery file will be loaded first. Also, this is a legacy code and it is not using any module loaders like AMD. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to include jQuery under a different name, or are you asking how to change your code? Your question would be easier to understand if you would include your code. How are you loading scripts? How are you doing modules?

Comment: @Bergi I updated my question and added these statements: "Note that we are working on a platform and we have no control on which jQuery file will be loaded first. Also, this is a legacy code and it is not using any module loaders like AMD."

Comment: @gre_gor I tried one of the trick there and added this line inside jquery.min.js (3.7.1) file: var jdnd = jQuery.noConflict();

The result is that:
- jQuery becomes v3.7.1 (this should be 3.5.1)
- $ is still v3.5.1
- jdnd becomes v3.7.1

Comment: @firnnauriel I read that version already. But "legacy code" tells me nothing, it could be anything. You're not using AMD, ok, so what *are* you using?

Comment: Wait your are going through the work to replace 1.10.2 by 3.7.1, but you are insisting on continuing to use two different versions? Why not also upgrade the 3.5.1 code to 3.7.1? Or upgrade from 1.10.2 to only 3.5.1?

Comment: @Bergi ok, I inspected the page elements and it is using <script> tags. it seems that the jquery that we want to include is loaded after the core jquery

Comment: @Bergi yes, and unfortunately, i have no control on the core page. i only develop on "top of the platform". and this "Platform application" is currently using v1.10.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255372/discussion-between-firnnauriel-and-bergi).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Bergi, I was able to resolve my concern. Here's the right solution:

- Open jquery.min.js
- Append `var jdnd = jQuery.noConflict(true);`
- Save the file

Again, here's what the previous team did in 1.10.2 minified file to achieve "jdnd":

- Open jquery.min.js
- Search and replace "jquery" with "jdnd"
- Save the file